# Can Prototype extend SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, svg, prototypejs

I'm trying to develop an interactive SVG map and can't seem to get Prototype to extend inline SVG elements. Here's my example code (path data removed because it's huge):

```
<svg id="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="330" height="500" viewBox="-16037,-19651 28871,44234">
    <g id="state_outline">
        <path id="state" fill="white" stroke-width="200" d="..." />
        <path id="water" fill="#a0a0ff" d="..." />
    </g>
    <g id="counties">
        <path class="county" id="adams" d="..." />
        ...
    </g>
</svg>

<div id="nottamap"></div>       

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($('nottamap'));
    console.log($('nottamap').identify());
    console.log($('counties'));
    console.log($('counties').identify());
</script>
```

The result of running that is:

```
<div id="nottamap">
nottamap
<g id="counties">
$("counties").identify is not a function
```

$() is just refusing to extend the element passed to it if it's part of the SVG element. Is there something about Prototype's interaction with XML elements that I'm not understanding, or is there a better way for me to go about this?

Comment: Fascinating question. I have no idea how the browsers implement SVG elements; they're clearly not DOM nodes.

Comment: JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SMTsm/

Comment: (Slightly different demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SMTsm/2/)

Comment: Perhaps you can "manually" extend the `SVG*Element` prototypes with the functionality you need, even if Prototype won't. I'd say they are technically DOM nodes, but they simply don't inherit from `Element` which is what Prototype extends

Comment: [$.identify()](http://prototypejs.org/api/element/identify) and a fiddle demonstrating selecting a purposefully "notanid" element that doesn't exist: http://jsfiddle.net/SMTsm/6/ (Result: `null`)

Comment: Continuing from my earlier comment: Yes, you can just extend the prototypes yourself (at least here in Safari): [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SMTsm/4/). Not the same as having Prototype do it for you, of course

Comment: Source code for `$.identify()`: https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/dom/dom.js#L2233

Comment: @Flambino - Be interesting to know why Prototype doesn't do this automatically for SVG, or if there's something else going on. It does find the DOM element successfully.

Comment: @Flambino, `SVGElement` does inherit from `Element` but not from `HTMLElement` which is what Prototype extends.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - Is there a solution that you know of?

Comment: @clockworkgeek I stand corrected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prototype augments elements through it's [`Element.addMethods`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/addMethods/) method. If you look at the [the source code](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/1fb9728/src/dom/dom.js#L3400) you can see this relevant part:

```
var elementPrototype = window.HTMLElement ? HTMLElement.prototype :
  Element.prototype;

if (F.ElementExtensions) {
  copy(Element.Methods, elementPrototype);
  copy(Element.Methods.Simulated, elementPrototype, true);
}
```

Here it favours the `HTMLElement.prototype` which SVG elements do not inherit. It falls back to `Element.prototype` in those browsers (*cough* IE *cough*) that also do not support SVG. You have the choice of editing the source directly and duplicating all copy actions to `SVGElement` too.

---

That sounds like a lot of work when you realise that a simpler hack can be used. The static `Element.*` methods still work when used directly. Instead of `$('counties').identify()` use `Element.identify('counties')`. Where you might do something like this:

```
$$('.classname').invoke('hide');
```

You can adopt the nice functional equivalent which is:

```
$$('.classname').each(Element.hide);
// or replace Element.hide with Effect.fade or any other effect
```

The downside is you lose the ability to use method chaining.

Answer (score 6):

clockworkgeek's suggestion to change the prototype source code worked very well for me. In prototype v. 1.7, all it takes is to change the relevant part to

```
var elementPrototype = window.HTMLElement ? HTMLElement.prototype :
  Element.prototype;

if (F.ElementExtensions) {
  if (window.SVGElement) {
    copy(Element.Methods, SVGElement.prototype);
    copy(Element.Methods.Simulated, SVGElement.prototype, true);
  }
  copy(Element.Methods, elementPrototype);
  copy(Element.Methods.Simulated, elementPrototype, true);
}
```

In prototype v. 1.7.1, the needed changes are:

```
var ELEMENT_PROTOTYPE = window.HTMLElement ? HTMLElement.prototype :
  Element.prototype;

if (F.ElementExtensions) {
  if (window.SVGElement) {
    mergeMethods(SVGElement.prototype, Element.Methods);
    mergeMethods(SVGElement.prototype, Element.Methods.Simulated, true);
  }
  mergeMethods(ELEMENT_PROTOTYPE, Element.Methods);
  mergeMethods(ELEMENT_PROTOTYPE, Element.Methods.Simulated, true);
}
```

I found the ready-made solution in [this blog post](http://firejune.com/1759/Prototype.js%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C+SVG+%EC%9A%94%EC%86%8C%EC%97%90+DOM+%EB%A9%94%EC%84%9C%EB%93%9C+%EC%A0%81%EC%9A%A9%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0?stag=Prototype)

Comment: Can you do this without altering the source?  Can't I selectively extend the Svg elements?